# jQuery changing class on toggle

Tags: jquery

I have an issue in changing class for the element collapsed but with my code it is changing class for every element.

```
$('.panel-heading').click(function(){
    $(this).next('.panel-body').slideToggle('fast');
    $('.panel-handle').toggleClass('glyphicon glyphicon-minus icon-window');
});
```

How can I change the class only for the respective element?

Comment: please share the html, you need to find the `panel-handle` element in relation to the clicked `panel-heading` element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use find function to get dom element inside your "panel-heading" class

```
 $(this).find('.panel-handle').toggleClass('glyphicon glyphicon-minus icon-window');
```

Comment: its accurate that's why bro

Answer (score 3):

Your selector `$('.panel-handle')` targets all the `.panel-handle` elements in the page, instead you need to find the `.panel-handle` related to the clicked `.panel-heading` element

I assume the `.panel-handle` element is a child element of the `.panel-heading` element, then

```
$('.panel-heading').click(function(){
    $(this).next('.panel-body').slideToggle('fast');
    $(this).find('.panel-handle').toggleClass('glyphicon glyphicon-minus icon-window');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 $(this).find('.panel-handle').toggleClass('glyphicon glyphicon-minus icon-window');
```

Comment: Thanks everyone gave the same answer.. +1